# Should I use "a X time", "the X time", "for a X time", or "for the X time"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Example sentence:

> He apologized (for) a/the third time, and I held back my complains
>   (for) a/the tenth.

What's the correct construction? And why?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible meanings that you might want to convey.

> He apologized the third time

The counting in this sentence is related to something other than the apologies, for example if he had done something wrong three times: the first and second times he did something wrong, he didn't apologize, but the third time he did apologize.

> He apologized for the third time
>   He apologized for a third time
>   He apologized a third time

The counting in these sentences relates to the apologies themselves: this is the third time that he has apologized.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20a%20third%20time%2C%20for%20the%20third%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20third%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20third%20time%3B%2Cc0) shows that **for the third time** is significantly more widely used than **for a third time**.